What's that movie with the bridge and its builder?
What's that movie in which some captive war-prisoner is assigned a task by his captor of building a bridge to protect the homeland from an invasion? By the time the bridge is complete, the war-prisoner who built it is so attached to his creation that he can't let the army destroy it. I have some bits of the story warped but the hints should be enough to help you help me with the name of the movie.

You are certainly talking about David Lean's Bridge on the River Kwai from 1957.Here's the IMDB plot description:After settling his differences with a Japanese PoW camp commander, a British colonel co-operates to oversee his men's construction of a railway bridge for their captors - while oblivious to a plan by the Allies to destroy it.Stars William Holden and Alec Guinness.It's currently at #100 in IMDB's top 250 of all time. Definitely a classic.Won 7 Oscars including Best Actor, Best Director, Best Picture, Best Screenplay (Pierre Boulle - better known for his Planet of the Apes novels, movies, and TV series).
